Claim for User Principal Name (UPN) returning null
I'm using AddMicrosoftAccount in asp.net core application for authentication.
now when I use _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() to get claim for User Principal Name (UPN) as follows
ClaimTypes.Upn() then it return null
I tried various options in the Program.cs file for AddMicrosoftAccount options. But that all are not adding desired claim i.e. upn

I can reproduce your issue in my side with codes
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = "ClientId ";
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
});

After sign in with microsoft account and asked me to create an on-prem account, I got null when get external sign in information. I'm afraid this is due to that this kind of sign-in is "not recognized" as an external account in some aspects.

Then I add codes behind the AddMicrosoftAccount, then I can get external login info.
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options => options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);


In the meantime, if we just want to get the user principle name, we might get it from data table directly as it use the email address to be the user account, which is the same as the user principle name.
